# ' vs " while using chars, in C

Tags: c

So I've been trying to use strcat like this lately and I've always got an error:

```
strcat(string, 'a');
```

And then I realised that I have to use something which contains '\0' as the second parameter, in order to have a const char* .

Well, I was just playing around in VS, and using strcat like this:

```
strcat(string, "a");
```

rendered no error.

This is very strange to me, because some days ago I've learnt that I need to create an auxiliary char, like this:

```
aux[0] = 'a';
aux[1] = '\0';
strcat(string, aux);
```

if I wanted to add only a character to a string.

Now I'm a bit lost to be honest.

Can anybody explain what's the difference between ' and " when using chars?

Thanks.

Comment: Single quotes for single characters. Double quotes for null.terminated strings. And in C a single character is usually implicitly converted to `int` values, and null terminated strings are really arrays of characters (including the terminator). A literal string (using double-quotes, like e.g. `"a"`) is an array of non-modifiable (read-only) characters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

String literals are implicitly null-terminated. These are equivalent declarations:

```
const char a[] = "a";
const char a[] = { 'a', '\0' };
```

Comment: Thanks. The example made me better understand.

Answer (score 3):

`'` (single quote) is for creating a single character which is almost the same thing as an integer.

On the other hand `"` (double quote) is used for creating a constant char pointer which means a memory block that is terminated with a null and contains characters in it.

You can put as many characters as you want in  double quotes, but `'` will always contain a single character.

Also you cannot compare double quoted strings for equality because, in the end of the day, what it creates is a pointer which is the starting point of your string which is a 32 or 64 bit integer on most machines. On the other hand  comparing chars (single quoted) is fine because they are values themselves rather then being pointers to addresses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your in-depth answer. Now I get it.

Comment: A `char` is an integer, not almost the same thing as one, right?

Comment: @FiddlingBits actually a char is a byte it is 8 bits on most machines where an int is likely to be 64 or 32 bits I just didnt want to make more confusion by talking about bytes and stuff in a beginner question